# Dagger custom scope, how to?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I need following scope structure in dagger 2.16 -->
[Custom Scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w69yj.png)

How can I do that?

*I dont want use dagger android support because its Beta*

I try this:

```java
//ApplicationComponent.java
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    ApplicationModule.class,
})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    UserComponent.Builder userComponentBuilder();
    ActivityComponent.Builder activityComponentBuilder();
 ...
}

//ApplicationModule.java
@Module(subcomponents = {
        ActivityComponent.class,
        UserComponent.class
})
public class ApplicationModule {
...
}

//UserComponent.java
@PerUser
@Subcomponent(modules = {
        UserModule.class
})
public interface UserComponent {
    ActivityComponent.Builder activityComponentBuilder();
    ...

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        UserComponent build();
        Builder userModule(UserModule userModule);
    }
}

//UserModule.java
@Module(subcomponents = {
        ActivityComponent.class,
        FragmentComponent.class
})
public class UserModule {
...
}

//ActivityComponent.java
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = {
        ActivityModule.class,
})
public interface ActivityComponent {
...

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        ActivityComponent build();
        Builder activityModule(ActivityModule activityModule);
    }
}

//ActivityModule.java
@Module(subcomponents = FragmentComponent.class)
public class ActivityModule {
...
}

//FragmentComponent.java
@PerFragment
@Subcomponent(modules = {
        FragmentModule.class
})
public interface FragmentComponent {
...

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        FragmentComponent build();
        Builder fragmentModule(FragmentModule fragmentModule);
    }
}

//FragmentModule.java
@Module
public class FragmentModule {
...
}
```

but cant inject provided objects in UserModule and get error.

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]

dagger not detect component path correctly:

> ...ApplicationComponent ? ...ActivityComponent

it must be:

> ...ApplicationComponent ? ...UserComponent ? ...ActivityComponent